# Elementary number theory with some arithmetic progression.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let

> **A={n∈N┤n is the sum of seven consecutive integers}.**
>   **B={n∈N┤|n is the sum of eight consecutive integers}.**
>       **C={n∈N┤|n is the sum of nine consecutive integers}.**

Find **A∩B∩C**.

I tried to figure out the sums of A, B and C using arithmetic progression by taking the first digits of the all the sums as a1, a2 and a3 and I got the following results using the formula

> **n/2(2a+(n-1)d)**
>   **A=7(a1) + 21**
>   **B=8(a2)+28**
>   **C=9(a3)+36**.

But I have not been able to generalize the things in order to get the proper result. The formula needs to be generalized for a proper set of numbers which would yield the required result. Please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline: A good start. Now use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to solve the system of congruences
$$x\equiv 21\equiv 0\pmod{7};\qquad x\equiv 28\equiv 4\pmod{8};\qquad x\equiv 36\equiv 0\pmod{9}.$$
The first and third congruence can be combined as $x\equiv 0\pmod{63}$, so we don't need to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem machinery. All we need is to find the multiples of $63$ that are congruent to $4$ modulo $8$.

Generalization: Suppose that we want our integer $n$ to be the sum of $k$ consecutive integers. Then the same procedure as yours shows that we need to have $n=ka+(0+1+\cdots+(k-1))$, so we want $n=ka+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$.

The number $\frac{k(k-1)}{2}$ is a multiple of $k$ if $k-1$ is even, so in that case we want $n\equiv 0\pmod{k}$. If $k-1$ is odd, then the relevant congruence is $n\equiv \frac{k}{2}\pmod{k}$.

Comment: Many many thanks sir @Andre Nicolas

Comment: You  are welcome.